# what is the meaning of "if (!J || !S)" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
var new= function(J, S) {
    if (!J || !S) return 0;
```

Can anyone help me to understanding this if condition?

Comment: There seems to be a syntax problem with your question on **new**.

Comment: return 0 if J or S are falsey (`false`, `0`, `NaN`, `''` etc)

Comment: `new` is a reserved word in javascript you can not use it as a variables, labels, or function name

Answer (score 4):

It is basically going to return 0 (a “falsey” value itself) if either of the arguments J or S are "falsey", which in JavaScript means they are equal to `undefined`, `false`, `NaN`, `null`, 0 or '' (empty string).

The intention is probably to check that the arguments are not missing before going on to the rest of the function, presumably because the function will error or return invalid results if either argument is missing.

Comment: `The intention is probably to check that the arguments are not missing before going on to the rest of the function` That was my thought, except it returns `undefined` if both arguments are truthy. Wondering aloud: do you think the function is checking that the returned value is `undefined` before continuing?

Answer (score 1):

The function returns 0 if either (`||`) J or S are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy):

- `false`
- 0
- '', "", `` (empty string)
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

If both values are truthy, it returns `undefined`.

```js
var nu = function (J, S) {
  if (!J || !S) return 0;
}
 
// booleans
console.log(nu(true, true));
console.log(nu(true, false));
console.log(nu(false, false));

// other truthy/falsy values
console.log(nu(1, 1));
console.log(nu(1, 0));
console.log(nu(true)); // S is undefined
console.log(nu('foo', ''));
console.log(nu({}, null));
console.log(nu(1, NaN));
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (!J || !S)` is checking if at least one of the variables `J` or `S` evaluates to a `falsey` value, and then the expression is going to evaluates to `true` and therefore execute the `return 0`.

But notice that you have an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'new'` in your code, and that is because `new` is a JavaScript reserved word that can't be used as a variable name.

Answer (score -1):

If J = "" or null or undefined, 0, NaN, false the !J will be true.

```
!"" -> true
!null -> true
!undefined -> true
!NaN -> true
!0 -> true
!false -> true
```

It will check J, S variable is empty or null or undefined or not.

Comment: you missed 3 other values that would also match

Comment: This is an incomplete set of “falsey” values. Including links to references also helps with self-validation.